# What resolution should I render art for a 3D game for PC?

Tags: rendering, resolution, pc

I hope this is not too stupid a question. I'm making my first game for PC and I'm wondering what resolution I should render the artwork at. It will be a fixed-perspective game, so I'm using a 2D background with 3D characters moving around.

How big should I render the background? Is 1920x1080 enough these days or should I go even higher? How big should the character textures be?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Other possibility - include the necessary assets, then render the background (once) at the desired resolution, if it's not one of the default ones.

Comment: You might find some use from [this previous question about deciding how to break up a model into textured pieces](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/160521/39518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is just not specific. What would you like to support? You can supply with the game a background that has a size of 1920x1080, and scale it down for lower resolutions.

Should you go bigger? Sure, if you can afford that, what if someone want's to play your game on a massive 40" screen? You can supply the biggest graphics, but then that one person with a weak machine and a 15" monitor, has to download massive assets to play your game and endure longer loadings.

So pick the highest resolution you want to support, and stick to that, at least when you are talking about 2D graphics. With 3D graphics, things should be easier as they behave like vector images.

Comment: For the sake of helping weaker computers, would it make sense to have several versions of the background images and use different ones for different resolutions? It doesn't seem, to me, that storage space is a very big concern to anything made the last 10 years, after all.

Comment: @Arthur - with SSDs becoming more common, storage is starting to be a concern again, though not as much so as it was in ye olde dayes, for sure.

Comment: @Arthur texture size isn't usually a big performance factor frame to frame — if you're using mipmaps, the GPU will sample from the resolution it needs for the size of the object on screen, even if the full texture is much larger, reducing the texture bandwidth and cache demands automatically. The whole thing still lives in video memory though, so storing a smaller version (or using texture compression) can help you conserve that resource if you find you're running out, and save on loading time when you first load the texture as TomTsagk points out.

Comment: @Arthur Sure storage space isn't that important, but if you were to jump from 1920x1080 to 3840x2160 (4k), that's not double the size, that's 4x as much. In most games, assets take the most storage space, which mean, if all your assets were made to support 4k, your game would suddenly be (about) 4x as big. A 10GB game is different to me than a 40GB one.

Comment: @TomTsagk Sure, but that wasn't my point. My point was which adaptation would be better for _weaker_ computers: prerendered lower resolution or render lower resolution on the fly. So it's not about going from 10GB to 40GB, but rather from 40GB to, say, 45-50GB (or from 10GB to 15GB). That's not nearly as big a leap, and to me (as a person who has no experience with optimising), possibly worth the lesser rendering load.

Comment: @Arthur downsampling an image isn't generally going to cause a noticeable impact, especially since you can do it once and save the result for future frames. Do you have any profiling showing that the time you're taking to lower your resolution is a major bottleneck in your case?

Comment: @DMGregory Not in any way. I thought it was clear from my first comment that I was wondering whether it even made sense. I have realised from the comments here that it basically doesn't.